# Matlab , suit a rotating paraboloid to x,y,z coordinates which are measured

Tags: matlab

I need your help in a task. I have measured a object which has shape like a parabola. i have X,Y,Z coordinates of the object. The task is to suit a rotating paraboloid to these coordinates, and determine the deviation(difference[dx,dy,dz]) between my parabola and the theoretical rotating paraboloid. Is there any way to do that in Matlab?

Thanks you so much, and sorry for my bad english, its long time since i've used it.

Greetings!
Daniel

Comment: Thus, this is a least square problem with a 2 parabola, right?.

Comment: mhh, this is a good question. my teacher told me i should suit a ball(orb or sphere) to coordinates. i did it successfully. After that he told me i should suit a paraboloid. Here is the point where i am stucked

Comment: so u are on the opinion that it might be a least square problem?

Comment: Yes, that is the way I would solve it. Indeed it is a linear problem easily solvable using matrices.

Comment: ahh, okay i see. Would you be so kind as to tell me how to solve it easily in Matlab?please

Comment: by the way what about paraboloid? it is not worth to do it?

Answer (score 1):

As you have only 181 points I bet this can be solved roughly like this:

Determine a range of parameters that definately contain the parabola that you are looking for.

Given these parameters, create a function that determine for each of your points the minimum distance between your points and the parabola.

Now you can just go over the range of your parameters in a smart way untill you have a reasonably good fit.